# An eigen problem

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$K$ is a symmetric positive semidefefinit matrix.
$K1 = 0$ (i.e. The sum of elements in each row is $0$. Or in other words matrix $K$ is centered. From this we conclude the smallest eigenvalue of $K$ is zero. With eigenvector $1$, where $1$ is a vector of all ones. )
Now what is the value of

\begin{equation}
\min_{x} \frac{x^TK x}{x^Tx}
\end{equation}
s.t.
$x^T1=0$?

Note: I still did not get why any eigenvector of $K$, nameley $v$, should satisfy the constraint $v^T1=0$?

Comment: What does $K1=0$ mean? And $x1=0$? And centered?

Comment: I take it you mean for $K1$ to be $K_1$, the smallest eigenvalue of $K$. Do you mean to restrict the minimum to vectors $x$ with first component zero? Is that what $x1=0$ (maybe, $x_1=0$) means?

Comment: Sorry, $K1=0$ means the sum of elements in each row (column) of $K$  is zero. Such a matrix is called centered. $x^T1=0$ means the sum of elements in vector $x$ is $0$.

Comment: Thanks. This information should be edited into the question, so people don't have to trawl through the comments to understand what's what. Can you do that, please?

Comment: Is the answer just the next smallest eigenvalue? If $K$ is the zero matrix, the answer is zero, right?

Comment: Sure, I tried to edit the question to clarify these.

Comment: No idea. Why next smallest eigenvalue?

Comment: It is the next smallest because the condition $X^T1=0$ restricts it from being the smallest. If it is perpendicular to $1$ (the vector) then it is not the vector $1$ (or $\vec{1}$ if you like), thus the minimum is the next smallest available eigenvector/eigenvalue. The minimum to your equation is the eigenvector associated with the smallest eigenvalue, but your restriction states it is not that particular zero eigenvalue/eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

The quantity $\frac{x^TKx}{x^Tx}$ is called Rayleigh Quotient. we have a principle called Rayleigh Principle: The minimum value of Rayleigh Quotient is the smallest eigen value $\lambda_1$. However the minimum of the quotient subject to $x^T1=0$ is $\lambda_2$ which is second smallest eigen value.

Refernce: Gilbert Strang Book chapter on PSD

Comment: Does the facts that minimizer without the constraint is the smallest eigenvector and that is not in the feasible set, imply that actual minimizer is the second smallest eigenvector? Why should be an eigenvector at all?

Comment: Where do we know that any eigenvector can satisfy the constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Every real symmetric matrix $K$ is orthogonally diagonalizable. That means if $u$ is a unit eigenvector of $K$, you can always extend it to an orthonormal eigenbasis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that corresponds to the matrix $K$. So, suppose $\lambda_1\ge\ldots\ge\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $K$ and $Ku=\lambda_nu$. Then there is an orthonormal set of eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ such that $Kv_i=\lambda_iv_i$ and $v_n=u$. Hence $K=QDQ^T$ where $Q=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. Let $e_n=(0,\ldots,0,1)^T$. Then
$$
\min_{x\neq0,\,x\perp u=v_n} \frac{x^TK x}{x^Tx}
=\min_{y=(Q^Tx)\neq0,\,y\perp e_n} \frac{y^TDy}{y^Ty}
=\min_{y\perp e_n} \frac{y^TDy}{y^Ty}
=\lambda_{n-1}.
$$
This is true regardless of whether $K$ is positive semidefinite or not, and regardless of the choice of $u$ if $\lambda_n$ is a repeated eigenvalue (i.e. the associated eigenspace has dimension $>1$). All we need is that $K$ is real symmetric. More generally, we have
$$
\lambda_k
=\min_{x\neq0,\,x\perp v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n} \frac{x^TK x}{x^Tx}
=\max_{x\neq0,\,x\perp v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1}} \frac{x^TK x}{x^Tx}
$$
You may view this as an orthogonal subspace analogue of the [Courant-Fischer minimax principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).